# How to pass an exception from the stored procedure to my Post Action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have the folloiwng Post Action method that passes two parameters to a repository method:-

```
 [HttpPost]
        public void Delete(string id, int classid )
        {
            repository.Deleteuserclass(id, classid);        }
```

where the repository method is :-

```
public void Deleteuserclass(string a, int u)

    {
        entities.deleteuserclass(a,u);}
```

and finally the repository method will call the following stored procedure:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.deleteuserclass
@userid nvarchar(50),
@classid int
AS
Begin

Delete from Users_Classes where UserID = @userid  AND ClassID = @classid
END
```

**How i can pass an exception to the action method that will be raised on the Database side incase the stored procedure did not delete any record?**

**Edit:-**
i update the stored procedure as follow:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.deleteuserclass
@userid nvarchar(50),
@classid int
AS
Begin

Delete from Users_Classes where UserID = @userid  AND ClassID = @classid
if @@rowcount = 0     
    Raiserror('No record deleted',1,16) 
END
```

and i updated the action method :-

```
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, int classid ) {
try{
                       Thread.Sleep(1000);
                       Users_Classes u_c = r.FindUserClass(id, classid);
                       r.Deleteuserclass(id, classid);
                       return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = u_c.UserID + u_c.AddedDate.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"), name = u_c.UserID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                   }
                   catch (ArgumentNullException)
                   {
                       return Json(new { IsSuccess = "F1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
                   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                   {return Json(new { IsSuccess = "F2" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
                   catch (NullReferenceException)
                   {return Json(new { IsSuccess = "F4" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {return Json(new { IsSuccess = "F5" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
```

but the problem is that if the stored procedure did not delete any record then the application will raised the folloiwng exception `NullReferenceException` on `return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = u_c.UserID + u_c.AddedDate.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"), name = u_c.UserID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`  ,, and it will not raise the exception that should be already raised on the stored procedure level `'No record deleted'`,, before reaching the `return` statment .. **so what might be the problme ?**

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is pass the return value from your Stored Procedure that is irregular.  You'd modify your stored proc something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.deleteuserclass
@userid nvarchar(50),
@classid int
AS
Begin

Delete from Users_Classes 
where UserID = @userid  
AND ClassID = @classid

if @@rowcount = 0
    return -1

END
```

I'm not sure how you're calling the stored procedure (not so familiar with EF), but you should be able to capture a return value:

```
// notice this method now returns bool instead of void
public bool Deleteuserclass(string a, int u)
{
    return entities.deleteuserclass(a,u) > 0;
}
```

And then in your POST Action Method, just test for the `bool` result of the `DeleteUserClass()` method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Delete(string id, int classid )
{
    if (!repository.Deleteuserclass(id, classid))
        // no user deleted, handle accordingly        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the stored procedure as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.deleteuserclass 
  @userid nvarchar(50), 
  @classid int 
AS 
Begin  
  Delete from Users_Classes  where UserID = @userid   AND ClassID = @classid  

  if @@rowcount = 0     
    Raiserror('User Deletion failed',1,16)
END
```

Handle exception and re throw in repository method

```
public void Deleteuserclass(string a, int u)      
{
  try{
         entities.deleteuserclass(a,u);
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
    throw e;
  }
}
```

lastly, modify the calling method as

```
public bool Deleteuserclass(string a, int u) 
{
    try{
     return entities.deleteuserclass(a,u) > 0; 
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      //handle exception
      logError(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply,,, see my update. i tried ur approach but the 'User Deletion failed' exception will not be passed to the action method...